# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "außer wenn" und "außer dass / es sei denn"?

Tags: grammar, difference, usage

Welche der unten genannten Sätze sind korrekt?

> Ich mache einen Strandurlaub, **außer dass** es keine Strandkörbe gibt.
> Ich mache einen Strandurlaub, **außer wenn** es keine Strandkörbe gibt.
>
> Ich fahre nach Deutschland, **außer dass** ich kein Visum bekomme.
> Ich fahre nach Deutschland, **es sei denn**, ich bekomme kein Visum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wie du auf [Deutsche Grammatik 2.0](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/komplexer-satz/wenn-varianten-selbst-wenn-ausser-wenn-es-sei-denn-sonst-andernfalls/) nachlesen kannst, kann man einen Wenn-Satz durch "außer wenn" oder "es sei denn, dass" ersetzen. Voraussetzung dafür ist, dass der Wenn-Satz negativ ist.

Ich übernehme das erste Beispiel von der verlinkten Seite:

> Wir gehen spazieren, **wenn** es **nicht** den ganzen Tag regnet.

"Wenn" + "nicht" kann durch "außer wenn" bzw. "es sei denn, dass" ersetzt werden.

> Wir gehen spazieren, außer wenn es den ganzen Tag regnet.
>   Wir gehen spazieren, es sei denn, dass es den ganzen Tag regnet.

Der "es sei denn, dass"-Teil kann sogar gekürzt werden. Dabei wird das *dass* fallen gelassen und das Verb wird an die zweite Position verschoben.

> Wir gehen spazieren, es sei denn, es regnet den ganzen Tag.

Dabei haben alle Sätze die exakt gleiche Bedeutung. Und zwar leiten sowohl "außer wenn" und "es sei denn, dass" eine Bedingung ein, die erfüllt sein muss, damit etwas anderes **nicht** gemacht wird.

---

"Außer dass" hat eine andere Bedeutung. Durch "außer dass" wird ein Kontrast zur vorherigen Aussage gezogen und eine Ausnahme dargestellt. Die Kernbedeutung ist daher "mit Ausnahme von". Ein Beispiel:

> Ich habe nichts mitbekommen, außer dass er nach Hause gekommen ist.

Der "außer dass"-Satz leitet hier also eine Ausnahme zur allgemein gültigen und doch nicht vollständig richtigen Aussage ein. Während es im Groben stimmt, dass ich nichts mitbekommen habe, so ist es mir doch nicht entgangen, dass er nach Hause kam.

---

In deinen Beispielen ist jeweils der zweite Satz richtig, weil du jeweils sagst, dass A eintritt, wenn B nicht zutrifft.

---

Nach Lesen meiner Antwort kannst du nun sagen:

> Ich habe nichts Neues gelernt, außer dass "außer dass" und "außer wenn" verschiedene Bedeutungen haben.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich mache einen Strandurlaub, außer wenn es keine Strandkörbe gibt.

und

> Ich fahre nach Deutschland, es sei denn, ich bekomme kein Visum.

sind jeweils korrekt.

Allerdings würde ich auch beim ersten Satz "es sei denn" bevorzugen. Zum besseren Verständnis hier noch ein korrekter Satz mit "außer dass":

> Mich stört hier nichts, außer dass es etwas zu kalt ist.

Comment: Danke, aber ist der Satz auch korrekt, wenn ich sage, ich fahre nach Deutschland, außer dass ich kein Visum bekomme?

Comment: Nein. Du kannst ihn aber auf "Ich fahre nach Deutschland, außer ich bekomme kein Visum." ändern.

Comment: Kann man bei Ihrem Satz auch sagen:

Comment: Mich stört hier nichts, nur dass es etwas zu kalt ist.

Comment: Ja, das ist möglich.

Comment: Ich finde "Mich stört hier nichts, nur dass es etwas zu kalt ist." hört sich seltsam an. Das "nichts" ist zu absolut und "nur" hat hier nicht die selbe Wirkung wie "außer". Ich würde daher bei der Verwendung von "nur", das "nichts" abschwächen, z.B. so: eigentlich nichts".

Comment: @Iris Ja, da haben Sie recht. Mich stört hier eigentlich nichts, nur dass es etwas zu kalt ist. Danke.

Answer (score 1):

Diese vier Sätze haben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen:

*"Ich mache einen Strandurlaub, außer dass es keine Strandkörbe gibt:"* Ich mache Strandurlaub, allerdings gibt es keine Strandkörbe. Von einem Strandurlaub würde ich normalerweise Strandkörbe erwarten.

*"Ich mache einen Strandurlaub, außer wenn es keine Strandkörbe gibt:"* Ich mache nur dann Strandurlaub, wenn es Strandkörbe gibt, ansonsten mache ich keinen.

*"Ich fahre nach Deutschland, außer dass ich kein Visum bekomme:"* Wie Janek Bevendorff bemerkt hat, ist dieser Satz inkorrekt, da der zweite Teil sinngemäß dem ersten widerspricht.

*"Ich fahre nach Deutschland, es sei denn, ich bekomme kein Visum:"* Wenn ich ein Visum bekomme, fahre ich nach Deutschland; wenn ich keins bekomme, dann nicht.

Zusammengefasst: **"Außer dass"** kennzeichnet eine Nebenbemerkung, die eine Ausnahme oder einen Widerspruch zu erwarteten Umständen darstellt, aber ansonsten für das zuvor gesagte folgenlos ist. **"Außer wenn"** kennzeichnet eine Bedingung, die nicht zutreffen darf, damit der vorhergehende Satzteil zutrifft oder eintritt.

Comment: Hat das die gleiche Bedeutung, wenn ich sage: Ich mache eine Diät, außer dass ich es nicht nötig habe. oder Ich mache eine Diät, außer wenn ich es nicht nötig habe.

Comment: Ich würde die Verwendung von *außer dass* an dieser Stelle als falsch ansehen. *außer dass* existiert als Subjunktion der Einschränkung, aber ich würde einen Nebensatz erwarten, der eine direkte Verbindung zum Subjekt des Hauptsatzes herstellt. Z.B. *„Das Wetter ist gut, außer dass es ab und an etwas windet“*. Die Verbindung von Strandurlaub und Strandkorb wäre mir zu indirekt. *„Der Strand ist schön, außer dass es keine Strandkörbe gibt.“* wäre hingegen ein korrekter Satz. Die Verbindung von Strand und Strandkorb ist enger als die Verbindung von Urlaub und Strandkorb.

Comment: @williclarkam Ups, sorry, kleiner Dreher im letzten Kommentar (hab den wieder gelöscht). Hatte deinen Satz falsch gelesen. Im Falle der Diät hieße es tatsächlich *außer wenn*, denn du machst sie immer, abgesehen von den Zeiten, zu denen du sie nicht brauchst. *außer dass* hieße hier, dass du sie machst, obwohl du sie eigentlich nicht bräuchtest.

Comment: @JanekBevendorff Das ist dann aber kein grammatikalischer Fehler, sondern höchstens ein stilistischer, der allerdings stark von den Ansichten des Sprechenden und der daraus resultierenden Semantik abhängt. Wenn jemand seinen Urlaub Jahr für Jahr im Strandkorb verbringt, ist für ihn persönlich die Verbindung von Urlaub und Strandkorb durch und durch eng. Dann wird er durchaus *außer dass* verwenden, wenn er von einer geplanten Ausnahme aus seinen Gewohnheiten erzählt. Ansonsten aber +1.

Comment: @AntonPoznyakovskiy Ich würde sagen, das ist durchaus diskutabel. Im Falle des Strandkorbes würde ich es allerdings als stilistisch nicht ganz schön ansehen, aber es wäre zumindest verständlich. Bei *„Ich fahre nach Deutschland, außer dass ich kein Visum bekomme“* wäre ich strenger. Das klingt für mich einfach nur falsch. Ich würde da eher etwas wie *„Mich hindert nichts daran, nach Deutschland zu gehen, außer dass ich kein Visum bekomme.“* konstruieren. *außer* dass heißt für mich hier nämlich eindeutig, dass ich nicht einreisen kann, weil irgendeine Bedingung (hier: Visum) nicht erfüllt ist.

Comment: @JanekBevendorff Bei dem Beispiel mit dem Visum stimme ich zu, ich werde gleich ein Edit hinzufügen.

Comment: @williclarkam: statt *außer dass* würde ich stilistisch folgendes bevorzugen: Ich mache eine Diät, **obwohl** ich es nicht nötig habe. Anstelle von *außer wenn* ginge auch **es sei denn**, dass ich es nicht (mehr) nötig habe.